# Using bootstrap makes some of the design disappear

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a website with ASP.NET MVC and I am a beginner to this. I have found a theme from bootstrap that I want to use as my design for the website. Before I copied the bootstrap css file into my css in the website, there was the original menu including Home, About, Contact, Register, Log In etc.

But when I add the css file from bootstrap the menu disappears and only the name of the page is left showing. I have copied the file into both 'Content' Bootstrap.css AND bootstrap.min.css, but is there something I am missing here?

https://bootswatch.com/journal/

Comment: Be sure to include bootstrap BEFORE your own css or it will override it. Can you provide some code of your view to help us to discover what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code in browser using inspect element sidebar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> shortcut for google chrome).
go to console tab and refresh the page to check if your added file paths are being loaded successfully or not.